# How to replace multiple span tags with same class name with a single span tag using PHP Regular Expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have to replace all the span tags with the same class name to a single span tag using PHP regular expression. I got to know we can do this by using DOMDocument and also by using javascript/jQuery. Also i tried with the code below but its close.

```
[<span(.*)><strong>*](.*)<\/strong><\/span>
```

Below is the code I'm referring to.

```
<span class="c28"><strong><span class=
  "c28"><strong><span class="c28"><strong><span class=
  "c28"><strong><span class="c28"><strong><span class=
  "c28"><strong><span class="c28"><strong><span class=
  "c28"><strong><span class="c28"><strong><span class=
  "c28"><strong><span class="c28"><strong><span class=
  "c28"><strong><span class="c28"><strong><span class=
  "c28"><strong><span class="c28"><strong><span class=
  "c28"><strong><span class="c28"><strong><span class=
  "c28"><strong><span class="c28"><strong><span class=
  "c28"><strong>Sending text messages that include links,
  attachments and/or
  pictures.</strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span></strong></span>
```

I want the output like

```
<span class="c28"><strong>Sending text messages that include links, attachments and/or pictures.</strong></span>
```

Can anyone please help me with this regular expression. Thanks

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2307070) about why ṫ̨̗̺̭̮̞̗̜̮̗̙̫̺̖̭̯͊ͨ̌͒̍͘͘͟͝h̸͓̩̙͙̻̗͔̞̘̟̩̯͋͑͂͐a̴̧ͨ́ͭ͒ͯ̓͐̇̃ͥ͢҉‌​̨̳̜̤͍͖t̵̳̳͕͉͋̓͐ͦͬ̈́̀̚‌ is a bad idea

Comment: How about getting the inner `<strong>` and put the `<span>` around?

Comment: It seems it's not only about `span` tags as `strong`s are automatically stripped out in your desired output too.

Comment: I think it's more ideal than using DOM here. It's not always a bad idea. @ThomasAyoub

Comment: `[<span(.*)><strong>*]` is not looking for a `span` and `strong` element, you are looking for one character listed in there. If the format is consistent (only span and strings repeating) you could use `strpos` to search for `<span class="c28"><strong>` if you have it strip all tags then prepend with `<span class="c28"><strong>` and append the closing.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could make use of the fact that you are targeting a *non-empty* `<strong>` with *text content* - which means you can use this fairly simple pattern:

regex: `.*?class="(\w+)".*(<strong>[^<]+<\/strong>).*`

replace: `<span class="$1">$2</span>`

https://regex101.com/r/mtUBWx/2/

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The solution only works if the class name is same(c28), but for us, the substitution which is made here the class name differs.

Comment: I've modified the regex and substitution string to pick up the class name dynamically, and updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

Nested `strong`s should be avoided. Also nested `span`s, regardless of their class names, which immediately come after the another demonstrate a misuse of HTML implementation. You may go with:

```
(</?\w+[^>]*>)(?1)*\1
```

[**Live demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uyNF57/1)

PHP code:

```
preg_replace('~(</?\w+[^>]*>)(?1)*\1~', '\\1', $string);
```